# In lisp how can I measure and capture the time spent evaluating an expression?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to capture the results of a call to the [`time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm) macro in order to gather multiple measurements and process them. I tried to locally `setf` the standard output and redirect it to a string but it didn't work with the `time` macro.  Maybe it is wrong, but what I tried is:

```
(with-output-to-string (str)
    (let ((*standard-output* str))
        (time (test-with-size 40))))
```

The questions:

1. Is a way to capture the output of `time`?
2. If not, can I capture the `slime-profile-report` command's output?
3. If none of the above works, how can I measure the time spent evaluating an arbitrary expression?

What I want to accomplish is to measure the run-time of an algorithm as the size of the input increases so for each input size (ranging from 1 to 100) I will measure a lot of times and keep the average. Then I want to plot the results. Plotting is easy, and I have found many ways in Cliki, but how can I gather the results?

I am using CLISP and CCL.

EDIT: [Paul Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26227/paul-nathan) pointed that the `time` macro outputs to `*trace-output*` which is a solution. I would like a nicer, simpler, solution though, because with this one, I have to parse an implementation specific trace.

Comment: Have you tried multiple-value-bind? Also, http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm says that it writes out to the *trace-output* stream.

Comment: thanks. multiple-value-bind doesn'work because time returns the result of the argument expression evaluation. But trace-output works, although it is raw output which I will have to parse. Is there any other more "elegant" way to avoid parsing this  implementation specific trace?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to capture the text, you need to use the right stream. The ANSI CL standard says that TIME prints to trace output.

So this would give you the text as a string.

```
(with-output-to-string (*trace-output*)
  (time (sin 40.0)))
```

You could also write your own macro using the time primitives. See [25.1.4.3 Internal Time](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/25_adc.htm) to get numeric data.

Comment: Paul Nathan also pointed that but still it is ugly... Parsing the trace... Also you need to supply a var name. At least clisp complains with plain (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*) instead of (with-output-to-string (var) (let ((*standard-output* var)) ...

Comment: Internal time is not what i hoped for, especially because of the notes in the bottom of the Hyperspec link you provide. Of course it could do  the quick and dirty job for a rough estimation if I find out how clisp implements all those aspect mentioned in the notes, but still it is not something I want to rely on if I want to present some results with an good degree of precision.

Comment: I wonder, at present, when someone needs to measure the performance of a  lisp "program" and publish some graphs of the measurements, how does he gather the information? Isnt there any recipe, or any pattern containing some the tools or language facilities used for this purpose? Does everyone write their own measurement toolkit?